# rc=2059 amq9503 channel negotiation failed

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to connect with MQ service and for ssl connection imported my certificate in `cacerts` file.

But when I'm running to connect, its showing below error

```
rc=2059 amq9503 channel negotiation failed
```

Do I need to create separate keystore and place my certificate in it, then point it using parameter `javax.net.ssl.truststore` ?

Answer (score 0):

MQ error 2059 (MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE) has nothing to do with SSL.

This error means usually means you are missing a client-side SSL certificate.

```
# Check your certificate installation path

javax.net.ssl.keyStore=<path to key store containing just your client certificate>

javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<password for that key store>
```

Comment: but if my certficate is imported in cacerts file, wont work ? Do I need to explicitly mention that ?